# How to bring out an Object that inside double array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to bring out object from an array which inside an array

from this
`[[{…}],[{…}],[{…}],[{…}],[{…}],[{…}]]`

into this
`[{…},{…},{…},{…},{…},{…}]`

Comment: what have you tried? try using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const arr = [[{a:1}],[{a:2}],[{a:3}]];

const output = arr.flat();

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply `flatten` the array:

```js
const arr = [[{a:1}],[{a:2}],[{a:3}]];
const flattened1 = [].concat(...arr); // With destructuring
const flattened2 = arr.flat(); // with Array.flat();
console.log(flattened1);
console.log(flattened2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use flatMap: `arr.flatMap(x => x)`